# Table of content in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, tableofcontents

How can I automate the process of building table of content in wordpress article in a one pager website I just made for testing this. I tried multiple plugins but they doesn't generate the table on the basis of H1, H2 etc?
Can anyone suggest?

```
<h1> Heading 1 </h1>
<p> content </p>
```

I want that to be automatically add in table of content. For sample content and headings check the [page](http://wanttobuystamps.com).

Answer (score 0):

Never mind got a plugin table of content plus. it did the job automatically. only not working on homepage.